# Fit the Slick Slider to container width?

Tags: css, slick.js

The problem is shown in picture below

[image]

I need to fit [Slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) container width but exclude last slide margin-right. What is the "correct" way to do this?

```
<div class="courses">
    <div class="course"></div>
    <div class="course"></div>
</div>
```

UPD:

I add negative margins to emulate full-width

```
.courses .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -22px;
}

.courses .slick-slide {
    margin: 0 22px;
}
```

Comment: The ""correct" way" of asking a question is to add relevant code in the question so we can help you

Comment: Are you doing margin-right on the boxes? Please provide the code for the slider...

Answer (score 1):

Without viewing your code the only thing that I can suggest trying is:

```
'box-class-name':last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps. If you are able to provide some code, I would be happy to help you further.